# Flexbox row layout with ul followed by input

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout with an unordered list followed by an input element.  I would like the layout to be one continuous row, where the input would be right after `item 5`.  It would also determine if the minimum width of the input would allow it to go right after `item 5`, or if it needs to go on the next line of the row.

I could obviously achieve this by putting the input in the `ul`, and I could also change the `ul` to be a bunch of divs, but all of this takes away from the semantics.  How would I achieve what I want with Flexbox?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 160px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: contents;` on the ul then `flex:1` for the input

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 160px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: contents;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 40px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width and use `inline-flex` and the container will only be as wide as it needs to be.

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: Very close!  The parent div does need to have an overall width.

Comment: Clearly your container is not wide enough to hold the `ul` in a single line. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Right, it lays out the items as far as its width can go, and then goes to the next line to continue wrapping the items.  If you move the `input` into the `ul` and add `flex: 1 0 0;` to the `input`, you'll see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `flex-flow: row nowrap;` so the items are arranged in a single row but would cause the container to overflow unless you set a max width to each `li`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 160px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: Close... the width of the parent div is not respected.